# Map multiple emails (git commits) to same user in TFS

Tags: git, tfs

I have an tfs 2017 Server with users that commit with a different mail address than the mail address set in the domain account.

Is there a way to add additional mail addresses, so a commit with this mail addresses will be assinged to the correct user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by edit the user's config info of the repo. When you first commit changes in VS, it will pop up a  dialog to add/edit **Git User Information**.

[image]

Just add email Address with "," such as `xxx@google.com,xxx@yahoo.com,xxx@hotmail.com`.

You could also change this in VS: **Settings--Repository Settings/Global Settings--User Name&E-mail** or directly use git command `git config --global user.email` to update the user's email info.

After this, when you check the author of commit, it will include the additional mail addresses for user account which commit/push to TFS. You could also filter the commit history with updated account in web portal.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what I searched, but it solves my problem. I didn't know that I could set multiple mail addresses. I would have liked to also show the correct user for already commited code, without rewriting the history.